# how to call methods in php from xml

Tags: php, xml, web-services, soap, xml-parsing

this is what I get from a company which is a webservice for buying a plane ticket.
they have some example in c# and visual basic. but not in php.
And I thing with soap in php i can call the operations or method or functions or every thing you guys say.
my code is this

```
$url='http://164.215.128.29:8080/Moghim24Scripts/Moghim24Services.svc?wsdl';
$sxml = simplexml_load_file($url);
$client = new SoapClient($url);
$data = $client->__call('openTempfllist', array(string fd, string ld, string cust, string pass));
print_r($data);
```

but it has some error.

you can open the url and see the xml code. the document sais:
 method1  : openTempfllist(string fd, string ld, string cust, string pass);
returns  dataset

but I dont know how to use this.
please do not tell me that this question was asked before. about 2 days i am looking for something like this, nothing i have found!!!!

Comment: What is the error message you are getting?

Comment: with the soap client, once a client is established, you should be able to call it via `$client->openTempfllist($fd,$ld,$cust,$pass)` hitting the magic method `__call` directly is redundant.

Comment: @jrn 

Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [a:DeserializationFailed] The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: Error in deserializing body of request message for operation 'openTempfllist'. End element 'Body' from namespace 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' expected. Found element 'param1' from namespace ''. Line 2, position 155. in F:\xampp\htdocs\test\ajans\xml.php:9 Stack trace: #0 F:\xampp\htdocs\test\ajans\xml.php(9): SoapClient->__call('openTempfllist', Array) #1 {main} thrown in F:\xampp\htdocs\test\ajans\xml.php on line9
this is error

Comment: @Scuzzy
I used this:
$data = $client->openTempfllist($fd,$ld,$cust,$pass);
print_r($data);

again there is an error:
Error in deserializing body of request message for operation 'openTempfllist'. End element 'Body' from namespace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yeap! found the answer!! that's it!

```
 $url = 'http://164.215.128.29:8080/Moghim24Scripts/Moghim24Services.svc?wsdl';
        $client = new SoapClient($url);
        $data = $client->openTempfllist(array('fd'=>$fd, 'ld'=>$ld, 'cust'=>$cust, 'pass'=>$pass));
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 try {
    $client = new SoapClient($url);
    $data = $client->openTempfllist($fd,$ld,$cust,$pass);
} catch
(SoapFault $e) {
    print_r($client);
}
```